# How to take screenshots of the old games

Tags: windows-7

As the title says. Right now I'm struggling to take a screenshot in **Hexen II** (this one uses **DirectX 3**) and **Wizardry 8**. I tried using **RivaTuner Statistic Server** (built-in MSI AfterBurner), **Fraps**, **Bandicam**, and even regular **PrtScr** key (print screen just messes up colors and inverts the image) , but didn't really work out.
So, how do I take a screenshot of the game that is REALLY OLD?

Comment: The [Hexen II manual](https://archive.org/stream/Hexen_II_Manual/Hexen_II_Manual_djvu.txt) says by pressing F12.

Comment: expect the output to be in BMP at best.  Probably will use non-standard palette.

Comment: Is this a problem specific to Hexen II? I tried using Zdoom for Hexen 1 and then Ctrl-PrtSc and pasted into MSpaint : there's no problem.

Comment: See my answer to [Software to capture screenshot in DOS mode](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/677/software-to-capture-screenshot-in-dos-mode/6796)

Answer (score 2):

Try downloading [Lightshot](https://app.prntscr.com/en/), no matter what game I've used it on it always works to simply freeze the screen for a convenient screenshot. It uses the print screen button too, but works better than the vanilla button.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Windows and have the Game Bar installed, `Win + Alt + Prt Scr` works nicely. The screen will blink-fade briefly to indicate an image has been captured.

You can find the images in `C:\Users\<YOUR_USER>\Videos\Captures`

Answer (score 1):

If you can run it in windowed mode ([DxWnd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dxwnd/) does it for many games) you can click on your desktop and use `prt sc`, everything should be fine.

Otherwise there's no other option that I'm aware of.